# Remove inline style when saving richtext editor text in database using asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, rich-text-editor

I am using jquery richtext editor, Is there a way to remove all the inline style that richtext editor add, as some users are adding there own style and its breaking the layout.

is there a way using jquery or C#

Comment: Including HTML TAG or only styles?

Comment: only styles need to be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this code:

```
private string CleanHtml(string html)
{ 
    // start by completely removing all unwanted tags 
    html = Regex.Replace(html, @"&lt;[/]?(font|span|xml|del|ins|[ovwxp]:\w+)[^&gt;]*?&gt;", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
    // then run another pass over the html (twice), removing unwanted attributes 
    html = Regex.Replace(html, @"&lt;([^&gt;]*)(?:class|lang|style|size|face|[ovwxp]:\w+)=(?:'[^']*'|""[^""]*""|[^&gt;]+)([^&gt;]*)&gt;","&lt;$1$2&gt;", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
    html = Regex.Replace(html, @"&lt;([^&gt;]*)(?:class|lang|style|size|face|[ovwxp]:\w+)=(?:'[^']*'|""[^""]*""|[^&gt;]+)([^&gt;]*)&gt;","&lt;$1$2&gt;", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
    return html;
}
```

from here:

[Remove Microsoft Class and Style attributes](http://icodesnip.com/snippet/csharp/remove-microsoft-class-and-style-attributes-code-snippets)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem myself and couldn't find a solution that didn't remove ALL tags and formatting. There were over 100 entries riddled with all kinds of styling that needed to be uniform. I ended up "resetting" them using CSS:

```
span{font-family: Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, Verdana !important;font-size: 12px !important;color: #474844 !important;}
```

Note: This didn't help with certain special characters, but it did make all the styling uniform. Hope this helps!